# Lifting varieties to characteristic zero.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, crystals, characteristic-p

If you want to compute crystalline cohomology of a smooth proper variety $X$ over a perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p$, the first thing you might want to try is to lift $X$ to the Witt ring $W_k$ of $k$. If that succeeds, compute de Rham cohomology of the lift over $W_k$ instead, which in general will be much easier to do. Neglecting torsion, this de Rham cohomology is the same as the crystalline cohomology of $X$.

I would like to have an example at hand where this approach fails: Can you give an example for

> A smooth proper variety $X$ over the finite field with $p$ elements, such that there is no smooth proper scheme of finite type over $\mathbb Z_p$ whose special fibre is $X$.

The reason why such examples *have* to exist is metamathematical: If there werent any, the pain one undergoes constructing crystalline cohomology would be unnecessary.

Comment: Even if such lifting always existed, it need not be functorial, which is a big deal for a cohomology theory.

Comment: I think very similar questions have come up on MO before.  You might try searching for them, especially under the tag characteristic-p.

Comment: Here is a link:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/423/what-is-an-example-of-a-smooth-variety-over-a-finite-field-f-p-which-does-not-lif

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This paper of Serre gives an example (I've justed pasted I. Barsotti's math-sci review).
(The paper can be found in Serre's "Collected Works vol. II 1960-1971)

> Serre, Jean-Pierre Exemples de
>   variétés projectives en
>   caractéristique $p$ non relevables en
>   caractéristique zéro. (French) Proc.
>   Nat. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 47 1961
>   108--109.
>
> An example of a non-singular
>   projective variety $X_0$, over an
>   algebraically closed field $k$ of
>   characteristic $p$, which is not the
>   image, $\text{mod}\,p$, of any variety
>   $X$ over a complete local ring of
>   characteristic 0 with $k$ as residue
>   field. The variety $X_0$ is obtained
>   by selecting, in a 5-dimensional
>   projective space $S$, and for $p>5$, a
>   non-singular variety $Y_0$ which has
>   no fixed point for an abelian finite
>   subgroup $G$ with at least 5
>   generators of period $p$, of the group
>   $\Pi(k)$ of projective transformations
>   of $S$, but which is transformed into
>   itself by $G$; then $X_0=Y_0/G$. The
>   reason for the impossibility is that
>   $\Pi(K)$, for a $K$ of characteristic
>   0, does not contain a subgroup
>   isomorphic to $G$. {Misprint: on the
>   last line on p. 108 one should read
>   $s(\sigma)=\exp(h(\sigma)N)$.}

Comment: The paper is available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181201150132/http://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/47/1/108.full.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

A general method for for constructing schemes with "arbitrarily bad" deformation spaces (including the non-existence of liftings from char. p to char. 0) is in the following paper:

R. Vakil "Murphy's Law in algebraic geometry: Badly-behaved deformation spaces", Invent. Math. 164 (2006), 569--590.

Answer (score 4):

In general the obstruction to lift a scheme $X$ in characteristic zero is in $H^2(X,T_X)$. For examples of $3$-folds in positive characteristic that connot be lifted in characteristic zero you may look at Theorem 22.4 in Hartshorne's "Deformation Theory".