# Quotient of Dedekind domains

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, dedekind-domains

Is there any characterization for a commutative ring to be a quotient of a Dedekind domain?

Comment: Let $R$ be a dedekind domain and $I$ and ideal, and let $\prod \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ be $I$'s factorization. Then $R/I = \prod R/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ by the CRT, and each $R/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ is an artin ring. So $R/I$ is a finite direct product of artin rings. The question is which such finite products can occur.

Comment: Make that *local* artin rings.

Comment: Another major condition is that the Zariski tangent space of each $R/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ is one dimensional. We also get a restriction on the residue fields from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/176117/existence-of-a-ring-with-specified-residue-fields/176194#176194 .

Comment: above should say "one or zero" dimensional.